# cross similar words in R

Tags: r

I want to cross two databases corresponding to a list of several products from two supermarkets, matching similar products, the problem is that although the products are the same, they contain small variations in their names, how can I match these products in R?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Check out the fuzzyjoin package. You could then do something like 

`library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_inner_join(Data1, Data2, by ="ProductName", distance_col = NULL)`